# How to fold backbone models, views and collections in vim?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, vim

I like vim's folding feature, but it seems to have some trouble folding backbone models, views and collectiond because backbone does not use traditional prototype syntax, but rather a .extend() based syntax.

What do I have to do to make vim fold this:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    somesuch: 'stuff'
});
```

Into something like this:

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({...}) --------------------------------------------
```

Any plugins, .vimrc hacks?

EDIT1:

I tried this myself, I created a file in .vim/after/ftplugin/javascript/folding.vim containing:

```
syntax region foldBraces start=/\.extend({/ end=/});/ transparent fold keepend extend
setlocal foldmethod=syntax
```

This does not work because it matches the first occuring `});` as the end of the fold, regardless of indent and whether it actually matched the start `extend({`. So if I have this:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({  // THIS STARTS THE FOLD
    initialize: function() {
        _.each(someVar, function(item) {
            console.log(item);
        }); // THIS WILL END THE FOLD
    }
});  // THIS __SHOULD__ END THE FOLD
```

Comment: A simple hack would be to use `set folmethod=marker foldmarker=({,})` but it's almost certainly a bit too crude. Did you watch [this vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/how-to-fold/) and [its follow-up](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/writing-a-custom-fold-expression/)?

Comment: I already have a marker folding for { and }, but for some reason it does not recognize parameter objects for .extend()... I will certainly check out the expression method!

Comment: I've tried creating a custom expression folding method but my regex skills are bad, so haven't been able to get something working yet :(

Comment: Feel free to ask another question, with what you have tried.

Comment: I have updated the question with the stuff I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually stopped trying to create my own folding expression and started trying out every syntax file I could find. I found [this one by drslump](https://github.com/drslump/vim-syntax-js) on github, and it has the folding style I was looking for.

It works nicely out of the box with the solarized theme, but I use molokai, so I had to change some highlighting for it to be a bit more fitting to molokai. The updated file is in [my dotfiles repository](https://github.com/jaapz/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/syntax/javascript.vim) on github.

It also contains some nice concealing stuff which I like as well.